# How to "force" Hive on Spark to use Map Join?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

Hive on Spark not using Map-Join for queries over a view which does a union all over several tables.

When using MR engine for the same query Map-Join is used.

I tried setting various spark settings as recommended by Cloudera - https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-13-x/topics/admin_hos_oview.html#dpp_in_hos

The view I'm using is a simple union all over some tables which all have identical structure and are partitioned.

The view is created something like this:

```
create view myView
as
select * from tbl1
union all
select * from tbl2
union all
select * from tbl3
union all
select * from tbl4
```

The HQL query I'm running has a "*where* clause" where a partition access is expected.  HoS fails to realize that, while HoMR utilizes the partitions and Map-Join.

Currently using Hive 1.1 (suggesting upgrade not relevant atm)

Thanks

Comment: Can you show exactly what HoS configs you have set, and paste an `EXPLAIN` for your query?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this Cloudera doc](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/admin_hos_tuning.html#concept_fjm_dry_y5), the following setting has direct impact on `MapJoin` behavior in Hive On Spark:

> ...`hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size`, which is the threshold
>   for converting common join to map join based on statistics, can have a
>   significant performance impact. **Although this configuration is used
>   for both Hive on MapReduce and Hive on Spark, it is interpreted
>   differently by each.**
>
> The size of data is described by two statistics:
>
> - `totalSize` - Approximate size of data on disk
> - `rawDataSize` - Approximate size of data in memory
>
> Hive on MapReduce uses `totalSize`. When both are available, Hive on
>   Spark uses `rawDataSize`. Because of compression and serialization, a
>   large difference between `totalSize` and `rawDataSize` can occur for the
>   same dataset. For Hive on Spark, you might need to specify a larger
>   value for `hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size` to convert the
>   same join to a map join.

Please see if this is applicable in your case.

Since we don't see your query, I'm not sure how is Dynamic Partition Pruning (referenced in your link) related to your `MapJoin` issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am aware of this setting.  I think the issue is different, and it involves getting Spark's optimizer to realize it can use partitions in the underlying tables.  When literally injecting the select command performed by the view to the query Spark WILL use map-join.

Comment: We may need a MCVE to better understand your problem then https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example